# How to rotate an iFrame using javascript?

Tags: javascript, iframe, rotation

I have an iFrame:

```
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
       <iframe id="camera_view" class="embed-responsive-item container well well-small span6" style="height: 720px; width: 1280px; background-color: #2e2e2e;" src="www.google.com">
       </iframe>
    </div>
```

How to rotate using javascript?

**Note:** I am using Bootstrap for CSS. jQuery for javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the `transform` property in css3

```
#camera_view {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

hope it helps