# Can i rotate the content of an iframe uisng JavaScript OR CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, rotation

I have the following iframe which show a chart as follow:-

```
<iframe id="customchart" src="https://apps.powerapps.com/play/*********" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
```

[image]

now i want to rotate the iframe so the chart looks like this:-

[image]

is this possible, using pure JavaScript or CSS??

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rotate an iFrame using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33727978/how-to-rotate-an-iframe-using-javascript)

Comment: @Rojo i already tried this css `#customchart{
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}` but it did not rotate the iframe

Comment: It might help if you post the relevant CSS

Comment: @Rojo my iframe is `<iframe id="customchart" src="https://apps.powerapps.com/play/*********" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>` my CSS is `<style>#customchart{   transform: rotate(45deg); }</style>`

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4920080/10210841)

Comment: @Rojo can i know which reply you mean to try?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229364/discussion-between-rojo-and-john-john).

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

Note: This will not work because https://apps.powerapps.com/play/*********  is not there but if you put in a other site url it will work.

```css
    #customchart {

        transform: rotate(90deg);
      }
```

```html
<iframe id="customchart" src="https://apps.powerapps.com/play/*********" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
```